# How to select all non-distinct rows from a DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by, having

This will give me all unique entries:

`select distinct (origin, destination) from mytable`

but how can I select all routes that are non-unique instead? So I get the rows that are dublicate regarding these 2 fields?

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. `(origin, destination)` creates an anonymous record type (with two elements) in Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT origin, destination 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY origin, destination
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```